# How do I disable functionality where pycharm adds linebreaks when pasting?

Tags: pycharm

Whenever I paste a long line, maybe 110 so chars long, pycharm auto breaks the python line into three lines.

I turned off the reformat on paste, but pycharm still insists on adding breaks. Is there another place to turn this off?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't solve the underlying problem but an `Edit|Paste Simple` did the trick